# is it possible to update document while functional find in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

i want to find a document with a simple condition but update it based on different conditions and cases .

this is what i wrote but i don't know how can i apply changes on `this` or `obj` .

is this possible ?

```
db.devices.find(
    function(){
        if ( this.unique_id == 'test' ){
            this.installed_apps = [{app_id:ObjectId("555390cb8af1031b237e2b32")}]
            //save changes
            return true
        } 
        return false
    }
)
```

Comment: Unless I am missing something I think all that you need is the update() operation: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
> db.foo.insert({"a": 1, "b": 2})
> db.foo.insert({"a": 1, "b": 0})
> db.foo.insert({"a": 0, "b": 1})

> db.foo.find().map(function(doc) {
    if (doc.a  == 1 & doc.b == 2) {
        doc.a = 3;
        db.foo.save(doc);
        return(true);
    } else {
        return(false);
    }
})
[ true, false ]
> db.foo.find({}, {_id: 0})
{ "a" : 3, "b" : 2 }
{ "a" : 1, "b" : 0 }
{ "a" : 0, "b" : 1 }
```

One problem with this approach is that `find` doesn't support `$isolate` so you have to take handle possible multiple reads manually.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the "findAndModify" method on the collection?

```
db.devices.findAndModify({
    query: {unique_id:"test"},
    update: {installed_apps: [{app_id:ObjectId("555390cb8af1031b237e2b32")}]},
    upsert: true
});

db.devices.update({
    {unique_id:"test"},
    { $push: { installed_apps: {<KEY>:<VAL>}}},
    {
        upsert: true,
        multi: true
    }
});
```

Comment: this is best way but if  `installed_apps` was not empty , other values will remove from array !

Comment: In that case the update clause can use the $push operator. Push will instatiate the field with the element as the sole value in the array. In the case where it is present the value will just be appended.